How can I programmatically determine if the used openssl lib supports TLS 1.0?
I need to determine if the openssl library, which is used on the system where my program runs, supports TLS 1.0 (or TLS 1.1) or not. I don't want to execute a shell command. I need to use C/C++.
Is the only way to check the version of the openssl lib? It seems the version numbers vary across different OS (RedHat, SUSE, MacOS, Windows), and the version doesn't necessarily implicate the supported TLS versions.

Define 'support'. All versions of OpenSSL (and SSLeay before it) implement TLS1.0 and all since 1.0.1 in 2012 implement TLS1.1, but versions since 1.1.0 in 2016 may be built with a default security level that prohibits actual use of TLS1.0 and possibly TLS1.1 unless overridden by either an API call or a cipherstring setting,, which often may be in a configuration file (thus the same OpenSSL version may have a different default on different systems, and even for different programs)

Right, I should clarify that my issue is, on a recent RedHat and SLES, OpenSSL seems to be built with a security level which prevents TLS 1.0/1.1. How can I check if TLS 1.0/1.1 can be used or not? I'll rephrase the question accordingly. Do you say I can overwrite the security level to enforce TLS 1.0?

Quite many software seems to trust OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER when checking functionality level of the openssl library.
// TLSv1.3 support is released by openssl v1.1.1.
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x10101000L
    // TLS1.3 supported
#endif


I think the version number does not really help in this case. See also the comment to my question from @dave_thompson_085.

Not a complete answer, but now too much for comments.
I don't know SUSE, but RHEL 8 (and I believe whatever Fedora corresponds) adds a systemwide cryptopolicy; downgrading this is simple but affects many other things also.
For OpenSSL in a specific program, you can call SSL_[CTX_]set_security_level directly or SSL_[CTX_]_set_cipher_list with a string including @SECLEVEL=0 (as in the curl example on the RH webpage), and if you use the generic TLS_[server_|client_]method (vs specific ones like TLSv1_1_method) you may also need to SSL_[CTX_]set_min_proto_version or the equivalent SSL_[CTX_]config to override any minproto setting in the config.
Or instead of explicitly coding, you can use envvar OPENSSL_CONF to have your program initialize with different configuration from the system default. Or for all OpenSSL programs you can actually alter the system config file, although that may put you in a fight with the package manager and/or policy manager.
I'm pretty sure I've seen earlier Qs on this -- possibly SU, SF, or security.SX instead of SO -- but Google isn't finding any for me.
